# Which indices of a 3 dimensional array hold the largest value?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, colors

I have a three dimensional array of integers, each dimension represents a colour R, G or B, and the integer represents the number of times a colour value of R, G, B has occurred in an image.

Now I need to find the X colours that have occurred the most in this image.

So far, I have created a list of structs, with the struct holding both colour and count. I iterate through the three dimensions of the original array, and for each value that is greater than the first item in the list, I replace the item in the list, after which I sort the list.

This of course takes a lot of time, nearly 2 seconds per run.

How can I find the X colours that have occurred the most in this array while doing this in a time-efficient way? At the moment it's costing me 2 seconds per run on my computer, yet this piece of code will need to be running on a Raspberry Pi, on which it takes a lot longer. Ideally, I'm looking for a 100ms time on the Pi, but I have no idea how to get there or what algorithm to use.

Edit: added the code on Jerry's request

```
// Struct holding colours & colour count
struct ColourCount
{
    public byte red;
    public byte green;
    public byte blue;
    public Int32 count;
}

List<Int32> matrix = new List<Int32>();
ColourCount[] count = new ColourCount[100];
int idx = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            if (idx < count.Length)
            {
                count[idx].red = (byte)r;
                count[idx].green = (byte)g;
                count[idx].blue = (byte)b;
                count[idx].count = colours[r, g, b];
                idx++;
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Sort<ColourCount>(count, (x, y) => (x.count.CompareTo(y.count)));
                if (colours[r, g, b] > count[0].count)
                {
                    count[0].red = (byte)r;
                    count[0].green = (byte)g;
                    count[0].blue = (byte)b;
                    count[0].count = colours[r, g, b];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
{
    matrix.Add((count[i].red * 1000 * 1000) + (count[i].green * 1000) + count[i].blue);
}
```

Comment: You should show your code rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: Since this particular piece of code is already taking ages to run, I guess it's safe to assume that it is not possible to improve it to a point where it's performant, so I left it out, hoping for a new insight. I don't think the code does anything more than described, but I've added it anyway.

Comment: It's the sort that is killing you. One way is to use a dictionary to hold the colors, add or increment them as you find them. Then sort once at the end to get the histogram or what ever it is you are doing

Comment: If all colors are known at design time, then just use an array, and index them. On saying that I am not fully understanding what you are trying to achieve here, though if you removed the sort, you will likely find this would speed up by factors

Comment: @The General I'm going to try with a Dictionary, and see if the performance is good enough. I don't quite understand your second comment - colours already is an index of all colours (with R, G, and B the index) which holds the count of colours. The question is how do I filter out the X highest counts. Is there a way to sort a three-dimensional array (if that even makes sense)?

Comment: After looking at your code, I am still a bit confused, however `var asd = new Dictionary<Color, int>();` then `if (!asd.TryGetValue(SomeColor, out var value)) asd.Add(SomeColor, 1); else asd[SomeColor] = value + 1;` This is a fast way of counting occurrences in some situations. Now all you need to do is order the results after the fact to get the highest...

Comment: @The General I've tried the method you described above, but this still takes about 5 seconds (which is longer than the 2 seconds I had before). This is still an order of magnitude to slow. Keep in mind that this is 5 seconds on my development computer, it should take no more then 100ms on a Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Move your sort. you only need to sort your array if you've changed the minimum value.

Avg time: 48ms, i7-6700k

```
ColourCount[] count = new ColourCount[100];
int idx = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
        {
            if (idx < count.Length)
            {
                count[idx].red = (byte)r;
                count[idx].green = (byte)g;
                count[idx].blue = (byte)b;
                count[idx].count = colours[r, g, b];
                idx++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (colours[r, g, b] > count[0].count)
                {
                    count[0].red = (byte)r;
                    count[0].green = (byte)g;
                    count[0].blue = (byte)b;
                    count[0].count = colours[r, g, b];
                    Array.Sort(count, (x, y) => (x.count.CompareTo(y.count)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jerry - Your code doesn't to the same as mine. Consider that count[0] holds the highest value at idx = count.Length, yet the next colours[r,g,b] is higher still than this count, then the highest value will be replaced in count, not the lowest. I tested this on my development machine, and it runs for 218ms on average. My machine may be old, it's still a lot faster than a Raspberry Pi, so I fail to see how this will run sub-100ms on a Pi. It's a start, but I fear still far from the solution I seek. Thanks for the info though!